# HttpClient PostAsync not working in CRM plugin

Tags: c#, json, dynamics-crm

I am trying to send json to a web API using HttpClient.PostAsync. It works from a console application but not from my CRM plugin. Doing some research I noted that it is probably something to do with the context the plugin runs in and threading. Anyway here is my calling code:

```
public async void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));

        if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target"))
        {
            if (context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity)
            {
                Entity entity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];

                if (entity.LogicalName == "new_product")
                {
                    IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
                    IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);

                    try
                    {
                        if (entity.Contains("new_begindate") && entity.Contains("new_expirationdate"))
                        {
                            await OnlineSignUp(entity, service);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (InvalidPluginExecutionException)
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(OperationStatus.Failed, "Error signing up:  " + e.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And here is the relevant code for sending the json:

```
private async Task<HttpResponseMessage> OnlineSignUp(Entity license, IOrganizationService service)
    {
        ...

        var json = JsonConvert.Serialize(invitation);
        var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Token", "token=7d20f3f09ef24067ae64f4323bc95163");
        Uri uri = new Uri("http://signup.com/api/v1/user_invitations");
        var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(uri, content).ConfigureAwait(false);
        int n = 1;
        return response;
    }
}
```

The exception is thrown with a message "Thread was being aborted". Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Update: only fails in debug. It actually works when I run it from CRM.

Answer (score 9):

I would guess this is going to fail somewhat randomly based on use of async/await. I wouldn't think CRM really supports plugins returning control before they are complete. When it fails, it looks like the thread was in the process of being cleaned up behind the scenes.

CRM is already handling multi-threading of plugins and supports registering plugin steps as asynchronous if they are long running (or don't need to be run in the synchronous pipeline). It would make more sense to use a synchronous HTTP call here like:

`var response = httpClient.PostAsync(uri, content).Result;`

**EDIT:** To illustrate, this is an overly-trivialized example of what is most likely happening when CRM goes to kickoff your plugin and you're using async/await (from LinqPad).

```
static async void CrmInternalFunctionThatKicksOffPlugins()
{
    var plugin = new YourPlugin();
    //NOTE Crm is not going to "await" your plugin execute method here
    plugin.Execute();
    "CRM is Done".Dump();
}

public class YourPlugin
{
    public async void Execute()
    {
        await OnlineSignUp();   
    }

    private async Task<HttpResponseMessage> OnlineSignUp()
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var r = await httpClient.PostAsync("http://www.example.com", null);
        "My Async Finished".Dump();
        return r;
    }
}
```

Which will print:

> CRM is Done 
> My Async Finished

Comment: I agree with this answer and would second the suggestion to move it to an async plugin - if you are concerned about delaying returning to the user. If you look at the plugin architecture of CRM it doesn't make sense to use async/await calls in a plugin. Since the pipeline is synchronous you already have a thread executing it you aren't really getting a user or system resource benefit from an await.

Answer (score -3):

looks like you are using Json.NET, when you use external assemblies there are some things to take care of (merging) and not always the result works.

Try to serialize using DataContractJsonSerializer

example: http://www.crmanswers.net/2015/02/json-and-crm-sandbox-plugins.html

Comment: JSON serialization not an issue.